# how to throw an error after retrying rxjs 6

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I'm having trouble with the return error in my retry sentence:

What I want to do is retry and httpRequest 10 times before considering it wrong, if it fails the 10 times, then throw the error to be caught by ErrorHandler:

```
private handleError(error, req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<any> {

  if (error.status === 0) {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      retryWhen(errors => errors.pipe(delay(1000), take(10), concatMap(throwError(errors)))));

  }
}
```

If I remove the concatMap it works, but with this, I'm not able to make it works. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a local variable to count amount of retries, or you could use a normal `retry`.

```js
private handleError(error, req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<any> {

  if (error.status === 0) {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      // delay 1sec in case of an error.
      catchError(e => timer(1000).pipe(switchMapTo(throw(e)))),
      retry(10),
      // after 10 times - okay failed.
    ),
  }
}
```

Comment: how can i count the amount of retries??? I'm not able to, and I would like to make this timer dependant on the retry index, it would be timer(1000 + index* 100)

Comment: inside of `catchError` you can do `index ++;` and `let index = 0` should be defined in the handleError scope.